# Why does my cronjob not send the email from my script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

Crontab script running from sh-3.2 (logged in as root) is:

```
* * * * * python /Users/tony/Documents/Python_Projects/Stock_Earnings_5.py #send an email every minute
```

`Stock_Earnings_5` sends an email based on the logic.

Currently `Stock_Earnings_5` works independently and sends out the email when manually running it from shell sh-3.2 (logged in as root).

crontab also works for "hello world" to terminal.

So in summary, crontab works for hello world program to terminal, and Stock_Earnings_5 works if called independently of crontab, but when crontab calls `Stock_Earnings_5` it doesn't send email.

Comment: This doesn't contain enough details to decide which FAQ it's a duplicate of; voting to close as incomplete. For starters, the syntax in `root`'s crontab is different (there is a sixth field which specifies which user to run as) but it's also plausible that your mail is not properly configured.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running which at least tells you what to check before you [edit] to provide more details. Probably you'll figure out what's wrong just by following that.

Comment: Keep in mind that the environment in which cron runs has different variables that your user environment.  Therefore, it might be (and usually is) necessary to provide the explicit path to your `python` executable.

Comment: @S3DEV, I don't understand what you mean.  I have the path where the python script is saved.  If I do python Stock_Earnings_5 from my current shell prompt it works just fine.  Can you provide an example of what the right cron command would be?  Thanks.

Comment: @tripleee, went to your link.  Still don't know what's wrong.  How would I force the path to be correct if it's wrong?

Comment: I think @S3DEV meant you need to change the replace the `python` in the `python /Users/tony/Documents/Python_Projects/Stock_Earnings_5.py...` line with the path to your system's python executable.

Comment: @martineau, how do I find where the path to my system's python executable is?  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure…maybe by typing the command `where python`.

Comment: @TonyD - `which python` - This will show the path to the default Python executable, which is loaded when you type `python` into the terminal.

Comment: @S3DEV, I did which python and modified the crontab script to : * * * * * /Users/tony/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/tony/Documents/Python_Projects/Stock_Earnings_5.py AND it WORKED!!!  Thanks!!!!

Comment: Excellent mate, glad to hear it.  I’ll post as a proper answer if you’d like to accept the answer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141380/cronjob-command-not-found

Comment: The first proposed duplicate does tell you a lot about how you would troubleshoot this. For a start, examine the system log files. If they are inconclusive, look in your inbox for an email message with an error message from `cron`, or redirect its standard error to a place it has write access to (append, don't overwrite; and of course, make sure you have read access to the generated output).

Comment: See [Running a bash script from a cronjob not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45743633/850848).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly post my comment above:

Keep in mind that the environment in which cron runs has different (minimal) variables that your user environment. Therefore, it might be (and usually is) necessary to **provide the explicit path to your python executable**.

The path to your default `python` executable can be found using the `which python` command.

#### Example:

```
$ which python
/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Then, in cron use:

```
* * * * * /home/username/anaconda3/bin/python /full/path/to/myscript.py
```