# crontab: Command not found when running Python script

Tags: python, shell, cron, environment

I wrote a Python script which backs up mongoDB, and it works fine when I test run directly in terminal.

However, I get an error from cron saying `mongodump: command not found` - although the command `mongodump` works fine when I run the script directly in terminal.

Contents of `crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * cd <path-to-script> && python3 script.py
```

Comment: [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62864649/6340496) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the post provided by S3DEV's.

Running the full env path of mongodump into the python script worked.
To get the full path of mongodump, in terminal:

```
which mongodump
>>/usr/local/bin/mongodump
```

In my case i am using os.system() in my script.

```
os.system(/usr/local/bin/mongodump [commands])
```

instead of

```
os.system(mongodump [commands])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because programs started from cron don't get the environment your login shell uses. In particular, `PATH` is usually quite minimal. The tried and tested way to run scripts from cron is:

- Always use an absolute path to a script in the crontab, say `/path/to/script`.
- The beginning of `/path/to/script` sets and exports `PATH` and any other variables needed, e.g. with `export PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH):/usr/local/bin`

You can test whether any script would run with a reduced environment with

```
env -i HOME=$HOME /path/to/script
```

If that runs ok, it is ready for cron.